# Filter or search NSCollectionView on macOS 10.11+

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-elcapitan, nscollectionview

I'm looking for a way to filter the items displayed in an `NSCollectionView`. My `NSCollectionView` is managed using the 10.11 and up mechanism (i.e. with `NSCollectionViewDataSource` and `NSCollectionViewDelegate`). I can't seem to find any documentation on how this is done.

Is it possible to implement a filter for the visible items, and if so, is there documentation available to show me how it is done?

Comment: What happens if you set the isHidden property on one of the item's associated views?

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I tried that experiement: when calling `makeItem(withIdentifier:for:)` to create the items, if I set `isHidden` to true, the views are not rendered, but space is still reserved for them in the collection view itself (i.e. you end up with just an empty rectangle where the hidden items are).

Comment: Ah, that stinks. Surprising, too, since this does work with NSStackView. Probably the way to go then is to make an array property as a sink for the "filtered" items, and when you want to hide something, remove it from the collection and put it in the sink. When you want to unhide it, take it out of the sink and put it back.

Comment: Use a filtered shallow copy of the data like `NSArrayController` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a better way, but until that comes along here is the workaround I found that doesn't require modifying the data source (which seems slightly cleaner conceptually, as the data shouldn't change during filtering, just which items are rendered).

Assign a `NSCollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` as your `NSCollectionView` delegate. Then implement the method `collectionView(NSCollectionView, layout: NSCollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt: IndexPath)` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscollectionviewdelegateflowlayout/1402900-collectionview)). This allows you to specify the size per item during layout of the collection view. I simply returned a 0 width and height `CGSize` for the items which did not match the current filter string. Otherwise return the `ItemSize` of the given layout. On every action of the search field (e.g. every keystroke), I'm calling `ReloadData()` on the collection view, which causes a re-layout.

One issue with this is that you have to set a minimum inter-item and line spacing of 0, otherwise the 0-sized items will still get the inter-item spaces, which can produce unevenly spaced visible items.

I'd still love to know a better way, so if future readers have one, I'll change the accepted answer.